# Check if there's an element in a list column in a dataframe

Tags: python

I tokenized a column using NLKT and now I need to check if each list of this dataframe has specific words. If it has, I want it to return (in another column) 1, else 0.

For example:

```
df = 

     tokenized
    ['this', 'is', 'a', 'tokenized', 'column', 'in', 'a', 'dataframe']
    ['another', 'tokenized', 'column', 'in', 'a', 'dataframe', 'blah']

list_words = ['another', 'hey']
```

**CODE TO RUN**

```
df = 

     tokenized                                                            contains_list
    ['this', 'is', 'a', 'tokenized', 'column', 'in', 'a', 'dataframe']    0
    ['another', 'tokenized', 'column', 'in', 'a', 'dataframe', 'blah']    1
```

- First row doesn't contain 'another' nor 'hey' -> returns 0
- Second row contains only 'another' -> return 1 (even if it had the word 'hey', it should return only 1)

I was trying this code, but somehow it doesn't work as expected (it mostly returns 0 even though tokenized column contains the element):

```
def check_word(words, search):
    if search in words:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

for item in list_words :
    df['contains_list'] = df["tokenized"].apply(lambda words:check_word(words, item))
```

Does someone know how to fix it or how to get another code to do it?

Comment: add condition if the return value is 1 then break, in the  for loop

Comment: So, for each row, you want `contains_list` to be 1 if `tokenized` for that row contains any of the words in `list_words`? The way you're doing it now, you're just overwriting `contains_list` with whatever value `check_words` returns for the last word in `list_words`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for-loop has a single place that it's storing the result in each iteration, so each iteration overwrites the previous, leaving just the value that `check_words` returns for the last word in `list_words` as the final value. Since your question suggests that you are getting fewer `1`s than you expect, I infer that you want a `1` if the list contains any of the target words. To get that, you can apply the `any` function to a comprehension going over the target words and checking each one for inclusion. The `any` function returns a booleans, and when booleans are converted to `int`, `True` goes to `1` and `False` goes to `0`.

```
 df['contains_list'] = df["tokenized"].apply(
     lambda t_list:int(any(word in t_list for word in list_words)))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how or why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.